# how to search for a href from a text file through python regEx?

Tags: python, python-re

I have bunch of output information messages through executing some CLI utility, and at the end of the file has a web URL. I need to use Python regex to find that link and show as a output. Below is the 3 lines of code that I have written for my purpose:

```
file = str('/root/PycharmProjects/rest_project/sponge_link')

with open(file, 'r') as fo:
    fo.read().__str__()
    urls = re.findall('https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+', fo)
    print(urls)
```

Below is the content of the file

```
INFO: Streaming results to http://abc/56659bf3-a66d-482b-80e8-6484cafc650d
INFO: Analyzed target <path/path/path> (73 packages loaded, 10521 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target <path>/dence up-to-date:
 utility-<path>/dence_0.0-5_amd64.deb
 utility-<path>/dence_0.4-5_amd64.changes
INFO: Elapsed time: 23.669s, Critical Path: 0.47s, Remote (0.00% of the time): [queue: 0.00%, setup: 0.00%, process: 0.00%]
INFO: Build Event Protocol files produced successfully.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Still uploading to http://abc/56659bf3-a66d-482b-80e8-6484cafc650d
```

However, when I am executing the program, I am getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/rest_project/sel.py", line 24, in <module>
    urls = re.findall('https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+', fo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 222, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

It's complaining that the data type should be a string. So, I used the `str()` over the file path, but even that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a `file object` to `re.findall`, instead of a `string`. You need to assign the result of the file read to a variable and pass that into `re.findall`.

1. `fo.read().__str__()` should be something like `lines = fo.read()`
2. `urls = re.findall('https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+', fo)` should be `urls = re.findall('https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+', lines)`